# How can I run a salt state if a command prints zero rows?

Tags: selinux, saltstack

I've got Salt and SELinux running on CentOS7.

I want to run `restorecon -Rv /path/to/something`, but only if it's necessary. I know that Salt has the `onlyif` and `unless` commands, but I'm having a heck of a time googling for what I want. I want to write something to this effect:

```
Fix SELinux Permissions:
  cmd.run:
    - name: restorecon -Rv /path/to/something
    - onlyif: restorecon -Rv -n /path/to/something produces any lines
```

I've tried the return code, but that's always 0. I don't actually want to run this command *every* time I run the state - just when the dir actually *needs* to change. Otherwise salt will report that it ran the command and there were changes even when there weren't *really*.

How can I get this to work the way I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this will do what I want:

```
restore selinux permissions:
  cmd.run:
    - name: restorecon -Rv /path/to/folder/
    - onlyif:
        - "if [[ $(restorecon -Rv -n /path/to/folder/) ]]; then exit 0; else exit 1; fi"
```